# Как заставить минус работать как операцию вычитания, а не как знак на PythonQT?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, калькулятор, pyside6

В моем калькуляторе не так работает вычитание. При нажатии на знак **`«-»`** число становится отрицательным, и должно происходить вычитание.

Нужно за **`"-"`** вычитать, а кнопку **`"+/-"`** менять знак на противоположный.

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tjn5D30Uk7o) на котором видно проблему.

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from typing import Union, Optional
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtGui import QFontDatabase

from design import Ui_MainWindow
import config

operations = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '×': mul,
    '/': truediv
}


class Calculator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Calculator, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("OneCalculator")

        self.entry = self.ui.le_entry
        self.temp = self.ui.lbl_temp
        self.entry_max_len = self.entry.maxLength()

        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("ui/fonts/Intro.ttf")

        for btn in config.DIGIT_BUTTONS:
            getattr(self.ui, btn).clicked.connect(self.add_digit)

        self.ui.btn_calc.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
        for btn in config.MATH_OPERATIONS:
            getattr(self.ui, btn).clicked.connect(self.math_operation)

        self.ui.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_all)
        self.ui.btn_ce.clicked.connect(self.clear_entry)
        self.ui.btn_point.clicked.connect(self.add_point)
        self.ui.btn_neg.clicked.connect(self.negate)
        self.ui.btn_backspace.clicked.connect(self.backspace)

    def add_digit(self) -> None:
        self.remove_error()
        self.clear_temp_if_equality()
        btn = self.sender()

        if btn.objectName() in config.DIGIT_BUTTONS:
            if self.entry.text() == '0':
                self.entry.setText(btn.text())
            else:
                self.entry.setText(self.entry.text() + btn.text())

        self.adjust_entry_font_size()

    def add_point(self) -> None:
        self.clear_temp_if_equality()
        if '.' not in self.entry.text():
            self.entry.setText(self.entry.text() + '.')
            self.adjust_entry_font_size()

    def avoid_deleting_char_on_negation(self, entry: str) -> None:
        if len(entry) == self.entry_max_len + 1 and '-' in entry:
            self.entry.setMaxLength(self.entry_max_len + 1)
        else:
            self.entry.setMaxLength(self.entry_max_len)

    def negate(self) -> None:
        self.clear_temp_if_equality()
        entry = self.ui.le_entry.text()

        if '-' not in entry:
            if entry != '0':
                entry = '-' + entry
        else:
            entry = entry[1:]

        self.avoid_deleting_char_on_negation(entry)
        self.entry.setText(entry)
        self.adjust_entry_font_size()

    def backspace(self) -> None:
        self.remove_error()
        self.clear_temp_if_equality()
        entry = self.entry.text()

        if len(entry) != 1:
            if len(entry) == 2 and '-' in entry:
                self.entry.setText('0')
            else:
                self.entry.setText(entry[:-1])
        else:
            self.entry.setText('0')

        self.adjust_entry_font_size()

    def clear_all(self) -> None:
        self.remove_error()
        self.entry.setText('0')
        self.adjust_entry_font_size()
        self.temp.clear()
        self.adjust_temp_font_size()

    def clear_entry(self) -> None:
        self.remove_error()
        self.clear_temp_if_equality()
        self.entry.setText('0')
        self.adjust_entry_font_size()

    def clear_temp_if_equality(self) -> None:
        if self.get_math_sign() == '=':
            self.temp.clear()
            self.adjust_temp_font_size()

    @staticmethod
    def remove_trailing_zeros(num: Union[float, int, str]) -> str:
        n = str(float(num))
        return n.replace('.0', '') if n.endswith('.0') else n

    def add_temp(self) -> None:
        btn = self.sender()
        entry = self.remove_trailing_zeros(self.entry.text())

        if not self.temp.text() or self.get_math_sign() == '=':
            self.ui.lbl_temp.setText(self.ui.le_entry.text() + f' {btn.text()} ')
            self.adjust_temp_font_size()
            self.entry.setText('0')
            self.adjust_entry_font_size()

    def get_entry_num(self) -> Union[int, float]:
        entry = self.entry.text().strip('.')
        return float(entry) if '.' in entry else int(entry)

    def get_temp_num(self) -> Union[int, float, None]:
        if self.temp.text():
            temp = self.temp.text().strip('.').split()[0]
            return float(temp) if '.' in temp else int(temp)

    def get_math_sign(self) -> Optional[str]:
        if self.temp.text():
            return self.temp.text().strip('.').split()[-1]

    def get_entry_text_width(self) -> int:
        return self.entry.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.entry.text()).width()

    def get_temp_text_width(self) -> int:
        return self.temp.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.temp.text()).width()

    def calculate(self) -> Optional[str]:
        try:
            result = self.remove_trailing_zeros(
                (operations[self.get_math_sign()](self.get_temp_num(), self.get_entry_num())))
            self.temp.setText(self.temp.text() + self.remove_trailing_zeros(self.entry.text()) + ' =')
            self.adjust_temp_font_size()
            self.entry.setText(result)
            self.adjust_entry_font_size()
            return result

        except KeyError:
            pass
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.show_zero_division_error()

    def show_zero_division_error(self) -> None:
        if self.get_temp_num() == 0:
            self.show_error(config.ERROR_UNDEFINED)
        else:
            self.show_error(config.ERROR_ZERO_DIV)

    def math_operation(self) -> None:
        btn = self.sender()

        if not self.temp.text():
            self.add_temp()
        else:
            if self.get_math_sign() != btn.text():
                if self.get_math_sign() == '=':
                    self.add_temp()
                else:
                    self.replace_temp_sign()
            else:
                try:
                    self.temp.setText(self.calculate() + f' {btn.text()} ')
                except TypeError:
                    pass

        self.adjust_temp_font_size()

    def replace_temp_sign(self) -> None:
        btn = self.sender()
        self.temp.setText(self.temp.text()[:-2] + f'{btn.text()} ')

    def show_error(self, text: str) -> None:
        self.entry.setMaxLength(len(text))
        self.entry.setText(text)
        self.adjust_entry_font_size()
        self.disable_buttons(True)

    def remove_error(self) -> None:
        if self.entry.text() in (config.ERROR_UNDEFINED, config.ERROR_ZERO_DIV):
            self.entry.setMaxLength(self.entry_max_len)
            self.entry.setText('0')
            self.adjust_entry_font_size()
            self.disable_buttons(False)

    def disable_buttons(self, disable: bool) -> None:
        for btn in config.BUTTONS_TO_DISABLE:
            getattr(self.ui, btn).setDisabled(disable)

        color = 'color: #E6E6E6;' if disable else 'color: white;'
        self.change_buttons_color(color)

    def change_buttons_color(self, css_color: str) -> None:
        for btn in config.BUTTONS_TO_DISABLE:
            getattr(self.ui, btn).setStyleSheet(css_color)

    def adjust_entry_font_size(self) -> None:
        font_size = config.DEFAULT_ENTRY_FONT_SIZE
        while self.get_entry_text_width() > self.entry.width() - 15:
            font_size -= 1
            self.entry.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: {font_size}pt; border: none;')

        font_size = 1
        while self.get_entry_text_width() < self.entry.width() - 60:
            font_size += 1

            if font_size > config.DEFAULT_ENTRY_FONT_SIZE:
                break

            self.entry.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: {font_size}pt; border: none;')

    def adjust_temp_font_size(self) -> None:
        font_size = config.DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE
        while self.get_temp_text_width() > self.temp.width() - 10:
            font_size -= 1
            self.temp.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: {font_size}pt; color: #E6E6E6;')

        font_size = 1
        while self.get_temp_text_width() < self.temp.width() - 60:
            font_size += 1

            if font_size > config.DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE:
                break

            self.temp.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: {font_size}pt; color: #E6E6E6;')

    def resizeEvent(self, event) -> None:
        self.adjust_entry_font_size()
        self.adjust_temp_font_size()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Calculator()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**design.py**:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget)
import files_rc

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 500))
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/icons/calculator.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"QLabel {\n"
"    color: #E6E6E6;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: #7a7a7a;\n"
"    font-family: Intro;\n"
"    font-size: 16pt;\n"
"    font-weight: 600;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: transparent;\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #666;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #424242;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.lbl_temp = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_temp.setObjectName(u"lbl_temp")
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lbl_temp.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lbl_temp.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamilies([u"Intro"])
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lbl_temp.setFont(font)
        self.lbl_temp.setStyleSheet(u"color: #E6E6E6;")
        self.lbl_temp.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lbl_temp)

        self.le_entry = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.le_entry.setObjectName(u"le_entry")
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.le_entry.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.le_entry.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setFamilies([u"Intro"])
        font1.setPointSize(40)
        font1.setBold(True)
        self.le_entry.setFont(font1)
        self.le_entry.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.le_entry.setStyleSheet(u"font-size: 40pt;\n"
"border: none;\n"
"color: #white;")
        self.le_entry.setMaxLength(10)
        self.le_entry.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.le_entry.setReadOnly(True)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.le_entry)

        self.layout_buttons = QGridLayout()
        self.layout_buttons.setObjectName(u"layout_buttons")
        self.btn_7 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_7.setObjectName(u"btn_7")
        sizePolicy2 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_7.setFont(font)
        self.btn_7.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_7, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.btn_4 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_4.setObjectName(u"btn_4")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_4.setFont(font)
        self.btn_4.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.btn_1 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_1.setObjectName(u"btn_1")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_1.setFont(font)
        self.btn_1.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_1, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        self.btn_ce = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_ce.setObjectName(u"btn_ce")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_ce.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_ce.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_ce.setFont(font)
        self.btn_ce.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_ce, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.btn_clear = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName(u"btn_clear")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_clear.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_clear.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_clear.setFont(font)
        self.btn_clear.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn_clear.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_clear, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.btn_sub = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_sub.setObjectName(u"btn_sub")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_sub.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_sub.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_sub.setFont(font)
        self.btn_sub.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_sub, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.btn_mul = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_mul.setObjectName(u"btn_mul")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_mul.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_mul.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_mul.setFont(font)
        self.btn_mul.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_mul, 2, 3, 1, 1)

        self.btn_div = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_div.setObjectName(u"btn_div")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_div.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_div.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_div.setFont(font)
        self.btn_div.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_div, 1, 3, 1, 1)

        self.btn_neg = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_neg.setObjectName(u"btn_neg")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_neg.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_neg.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_neg.setFont(font)
        self.btn_neg.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_neg, 3, 3, 1, 1)

        self.btn_add = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_add.setObjectName(u"btn_add")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_add.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_add.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_add.setFont(font)
        self.btn_add.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_add, 4, 3, 1, 1)

        self.btn_calc = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_calc.setObjectName(u"btn_calc")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_calc.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_calc.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_calc.setFont(font)
        self.btn_calc.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_calc, 5, 3, 1, 1)

        self.btn_backspace = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_backspace.setObjectName(u"btn_backspace")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_backspace.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_backspace.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_backspace.setFont(font)
        self.btn_backspace.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        icon1 = QIcon()
        icon1.addFile(u":/icons/outline_backspace_white_24dp.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_backspace.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_backspace.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_backspace, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.btn_9 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_9.setObjectName(u"btn_9")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_9.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_9.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_9.setFont(font)
        self.btn_9.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        self.btn_6 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_6.setObjectName(u"btn_6")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_6.setFont(font)
        self.btn_6.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_6, 3, 2, 1, 1)

        self.btn_3 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_3.setObjectName(u"btn_3")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_3.setFont(font)
        self.btn_3.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_3, 4, 2, 1, 1)

        self.btn_point = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_point.setObjectName(u"btn_point")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_point.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_point.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_point.setFont(font)
        self.btn_point.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_point, 5, 2, 1, 1)

        self.btn_8 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_8.setObjectName(u"btn_8")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_8.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_8.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_8.setFont(font)
        self.btn_8.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_8, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.btn_5 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_5.setObjectName(u"btn_5")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_5.setFont(font)
        self.btn_5.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_5, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        self.btn_2 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_2.setObjectName(u"btn_2")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_2.setFont(font)
        self.btn_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_2, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.btn_0 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_0.setObjectName(u"btn_0")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.btn_0.setFont(font)
        self.btn_0.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn_0.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))

        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_0, 5, 1, 1, 1)


        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.layout_buttons)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"OneCalculator", None))
        self.lbl_temp.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"", None))
        self.le_entry.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
        self.btn_7.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None))
        self.btn_7.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None))
        self.btn_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None))
        self.btn_4.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None))
        self.btn_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None))
        self.btn_1.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None))
        self.btn_ce.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"CE", None))
        self.btn_ce.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Del", None))
        self.btn_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"C", None))
        self.btn_sub.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+/-", None))
        self.btn_mul.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00d7", None))
        self.btn_mul.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"*", None))
        self.btn_div.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"/", None))
        self.btn_div.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"/", None))
        self.btn_neg.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"-", None))
        self.btn_neg.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"-", None))
        self.btn_add.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+", None))
        self.btn_add.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+", None))
        self.btn_calc.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"=", None))
        self.btn_calc.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"=", None))
        self.btn_backspace.setText("")
        self.btn_backspace.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Backspace", None))
        self.btn_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None))
        self.btn_9.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None))
        self.btn_6.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None))
        self.btn_6.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None))
        self.btn_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None))
        self.btn_3.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None))
        self.btn_point.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u".", None))
        self.btn_point.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u".", None))
        self.btn_8.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None))
        self.btn_8.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None))
        self.btn_5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None))
        self.btn_5.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None))
        self.btn_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None))
        self.btn_2.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None))
        self.btn_0.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
        self.btn_0.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
```

**config.py**

```py
ERROR_ZERO_DIV = 'Division by zero'
ERROR_UNDEFINED = 'Result is undefined'

DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 16
DEFAULT_ENTRY_FONT_SIZE = 40

DIGIT_BUTTONS = [f'btn_{num}' for num in range(10)]
MATH_OPERATIONS = ['btn_add', 'btn_sub', 'btn_mul', 'btn_div']
BUTTONS_TO_DISABLE = [
    'btn_calc', 'btn_add', 'btn_sub',
    'btn_mul', 'btn_div', 'btn_neg', 'btn_point'
]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick Я виправив приклад, можливо, саме в цьому відрізку коду є помилка.

Comment: marcAvn, без воспроизводимого примера ничего сказать не возможно. Проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1419509/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0/1419565#1419565

Comment: Для воспроизводимого кода нахватает одного файла, но из-за ограничения в символах я не могу его вставить, что делать?

Comment: marcAvn что не так в моем втором ответе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я исправил три строки в вашем коде:

1 . в **main.py**:

```
# !!! - btn_neg - negate     
#        self.ui.btn_neg.clicked.connect(self.negate)
        self.ui.btn_sub.clicked.connect(self.negate)        
# ------------> ^^^^^^^ <-------------------------------------------------  btn_sub !!!
```

2 . в **config.py**:

```
# !!! - MATH_OPERATIONS = ['btn_add', 'btn_sub', 'btn_mul', 'btn_div']
MATH_OPERATIONS = ['btn_add', 'btn_neg', 'btn_mul', 'btn_div']
# ---------------------------> ^^^^^^^ <----------------------------------  btn_neg !!!
```

3 . в **design.py**:

замените строку `"color: #white;")` на строку `"color: white;")`

---

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from typing import Union, Optional
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtGui import QFontDatabase
'''
from design import Ui_MainWindow          
import config                                

operations = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '×': mul,
    '/': truediv
}


class Calculator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Calculator, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("OneCalculator")

        self.entry = self.ui.le_entry
        self.temp = self.ui.lbl_temp
        self.entry_max_len = self.entry.maxLength()

        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("ui/fonts/Intro.ttf")

        for btn in q1445887_config.DIGIT_BUTTONS:
            getattr(self.ui, btn).clicked.connect(self.add_digit)        # цифры

        self.ui.btn_calc.clicked.connect(self.calculate)                 # calculate =
        
        for btn in q1445887_config.MATH_OPERATIONS:
            getattr(self.ui, btn).clicked.connect(self.math_operation)   # math_operation

        self.ui.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_all)
        self.ui.btn_ce.clicked.connect(self.clear_entry)
        self.ui.btn_point.clicked.connect(self.add_point)
        
# !!! - btn_neg - negate     
#        self.ui.btn_neg.clicked.connect(self.negate)
        self.ui.btn_sub.clicked.connect(self.negate)        
# ------------> ^^^^^^^ <-------------------------------------------------  btn_sub !!!
        
        self.ui.btn_backspace.clicked.connect(self.backspace)

    def add_digit(self) -> None:
...
```

**config.py**

```
ERROR_ZERO_DIV = 'Division by zero'
ERROR_UNDEFINED = 'Result is undefined'

DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 16
DEFAULT_ENTRY_FONT_SIZE = 40

DIGIT_BUTTONS = [f'btn_{num}' for num in range(10)]

# !!! - MATH_OPERATIONS = ['btn_add', 'btn_sub', 'btn_mul', 'btn_div']
MATH_OPERATIONS = ['btn_add', 'btn_neg', 'btn_mul', 'btn_div']
# ---------------------------> ^^^^^^^ <----------------------------------  btn_neg !!!

BUTTONS_TO_DISABLE = [
    'btn_calc', 'btn_add', 'btn_sub',
    'btn_mul', 'btn_div', 'btn_neg', 'btn_point'
]
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @marcAvn что не так в моем втором ответе?

Comment: Все отлично! Я понял в чем суть, просто перепутал "neg" и "sub". Спасибо большое, что помогли разобраться.

Comment: @marcAvn пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Без воспроизводимого примера ничего сказать не могу.

Пример, ссылку которого я вам предоставил в комментариях, видимо вам не подошел.

Вот вам вариант покруче, попробуйте.

```
import math
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLayout, QLineEdit,
                             QSizePolicy,  QToolButton, QWidget)


class Button(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.setText(text)

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super(Button, self).sizeHint()
        size.setHeight(size.height() + 20)    
        size.setWidth(max(size.width(), size.height()))
        return size


class Calculator(QWidget):
    NumDigitButtons = 10
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Calculator, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pendingAdditiveOperator       = ''  # ожидающий аддитивный оператор
        self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''  # ожидающий мультипликативный оператор

        self.sumInMemory       = 0.0
        self.sumSoFar          = 0.0
        self.factorSoFar       = 0.0
        self.waitingForOperand = True

        self.display = QLineEdit('0')
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.display.setMaxLength(15)
        font = self.display.font()
        font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() + 8)
        self.display.setFont(font)

        self.digitButtons = []
        
        for i in range(Calculator.NumDigitButtons):
            self.digitButtons.append(self.createButton(str(i),
                                     self.digitClicked))

        self.pointButton      = self.createButton(".", self.pointClicked)
        self.changeSignButton = self.createButton(u"\N{PLUS-MINUS SIGN}",
                self.changeSignClicked)

        self.backspaceButton = self.createButton("Backspace",
                                                  self.backspaceClicked)
        self.clearButton     = self.createButton("Clear",     self.clear)
        self.clearAllButton  = self.createButton("Clear All", self.clearAll)

        self.clearMemoryButton = self.createButton("MC", self.clearMemory)
        self.readMemoryButton  = self.createButton("MR", self.readMemory)
        self.setMemoryButton   = self.createButton("MS", self.setMemory)
        self.addToMemoryButton = self.createButton("M+", self.addToMemory)

        self.divisionButton = self.createButton(u"\N{DIVISION SIGN}",
                self.multiplicativeOperatorClicked)
        self.timesButton = self.createButton(u"\N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN}",
                self.multiplicativeOperatorClicked)
        self.minusButton = self.createButton("-", self.additiveOperatorClicked)
        self.plusButton  = self.createButton("+", self.additiveOperatorClicked)

        self.squareRootButton = self.createButton("Sqrt",
                self.unaryOperatorClicked)
        self.powerButton = self.createButton(u"x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}",
                self.unaryOperatorClicked)
        self.reciprocalButton = self.createButton("1/x",
                self.unaryOperatorClicked)
        self.equalButton = self.createButton("=", self.equalClicked)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.display,         0, 0, 1, 6)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.backspaceButton, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.clearButton,     1, 2, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.clearAllButton,  1, 4, 1, 2)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.clearMemoryButton, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.readMemoryButton,  3, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.setMemoryButton,   4, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.addToMemoryButton, 5, 0)

        for i in range(1, Calculator.NumDigitButtons):
            row    = ((9 - i) / 3) + 2
            column = ((i - 1) % 3) + 1
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.digitButtons[i], row, column)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.digitButtons[0],  5, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pointButton,      5, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.changeSignButton, 5, 3)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.divisionButton, 2, 4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.timesButton,    3, 4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.minusButton,    4, 4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.plusButton,     5, 4)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.squareRootButton, 2, 5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.powerButton,      3, 5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.reciprocalButton, 4, 5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.equalButton,      5, 5)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Calculator")

    def digitClicked(self):
        clickedButton = self.sender()
        digitValue    = int(clickedButton.text())

        if self.display.text() == '0' and digitValue == 0.0:
            return

        if self.waitingForOperand:
            self.display.clear()
            self.waitingForOperand = False

        self.display.setText(self.display.text() + str(digitValue))

    def unaryOperatorClicked(self):
        clickedButton   = self.sender()
        clickedOperator = clickedButton.text()
        operand         = float(self.display.text())

        if clickedOperator == "Sqrt":
            if operand < 0.0:
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            result = math.sqrt(operand)
        elif clickedOperator == u"x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}":
            result = math.pow(operand, 2.0)
        elif clickedOperator == "1/x":
            if operand == 0.0:
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            result = 1.0 / operand

        self.display.setText(str(result))
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def additiveOperatorClicked(self):
        clickedButton   = self.sender()
        clickedOperator = clickedButton.text()
        operand         = float(self.display.text())

        if self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.display.setText(str(self.factorSoFar))
            operand          = self.factorSoFar
            self.factorSoFar = 0.0
            self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''

        if self.pendingAdditiveOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingAdditiveOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.display.setText(str(self.sumSoFar))
        else:
            self.sumSoFar = operand

        self.pendingAdditiveOperator = clickedOperator
        self.waitingForOperand       = True

    def multiplicativeOperatorClicked(self):
        clickedButton   = self.sender()
        clickedOperator = clickedButton.text()
        operand         = float(self.display.text())

        if self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.display.setText(str(self.factorSoFar))
        else:
            self.factorSoFar = operand

        self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = clickedOperator
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def equalClicked(self):
        operand = float(self.display.text())

        if self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            operand          = self.factorSoFar
            self.factorSoFar = 0.0
            self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''

        if self.pendingAdditiveOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingAdditiveOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.pendingAdditiveOperator = ''
        else:
            self.sumSoFar = operand

        self.display.setText(str(self.sumSoFar))
        self.sumSoFar = 0.0
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def pointClicked(self):
        if self.waitingForOperand:
            self.display.setText('0')

        if "." not in self.display.text():
            self.display.setText(self.display.text() + ".")

        self.waitingForOperand = False

    def changeSignClicked(self):
        text  = self.display.text()
        value = float(text)

        if value > 0.0:
            text = "-" + text
        elif value < 0.0:
            text = text[1:]

        self.display.setText(text)

    def backspaceClicked(self):
        if self.waitingForOperand:
            return

        text = self.display.text()[:-1]
        if not text:
            text = '0'
            self.waitingForOperand = True

        self.display.setText(text)

    def clear(self):
        if self.waitingForOperand:
            return

        self.display.setText('0')
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def clearAll(self):
        self.sumSoFar    = 0.0
        self.factorSoFar = 0.0
        self.pendingAdditiveOperator       = ''
        self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''
        self.display.setText('0')
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def clearMemory(self):
        self.sumInMemory = 0.0

    def readMemory(self):
        self.display.setText(str(self.sumInMemory))
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def setMemory(self):
        self.equalClicked()
        self.sumInMemory = float(self.display.text())

    def addToMemory(self):
        self.equalClicked()
        self.sumInMemory += float(self.display.text())

    def createButton(self, text, member):
        button = Button(text)
        button.clicked.connect(member)
        return button

    def abortOperation(self):
        self.clearAll()
        self.display.setText("####")

    def calculate(self, rightOperand, pendingOperator):
        if pendingOperator == "+":
            self.sumSoFar += rightOperand
        elif pendingOperator == "-":
            self.sumSoFar -= rightOperand
        elif pendingOperator == u"\N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN}":
            self.factorSoFar *= rightOperand
        elif pendingOperator == u"\N{DIVISION SIGN}":
            if rightOperand == 0.0:
                return False

            self.factorSoFar /= rightOperand

        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    calc = Calculator()
    calc.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В результате исследований выяснилось что кнопки <kbd>+/-</kbd> и <kbd>-</kbd> были перепутаны в разметке:

В функуии `retranslateUi` заменены строки:

```
self.btn_sub.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+/-", None))
self.btn_neg.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"-", None))
self.btn_neg.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"-", None))
```

на

```
self.btn_neg.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+/-", None))
self.btn_sub.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"-", None))
self.btn_sub.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"-", None))
```

И заменены строки отвечающие за расположение этих кнопок

```
self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_sub, 5, 0, 1, 1)
self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_neg, 3, 3, 1, 1)
```

на

```
self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_sub, 3, 3, 1, 1)
self.layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_neg, 5, 0, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Понимаете тут дело принципа. Хочу довести до ума данный код и все что мне надо, чтобы работало как надо вычитание. А также есть проблема с клавишей смены знака, её тоже надо исправить.

Comment: Понимаю, это здорово что есть такое желание, особенно если разобраться до конца, видите то как влияет указанный тут код на результат?

Comment: Понимаю ли я код, полностью, до конца? Нет. Но никто не заходит в какой-либо род деятельности гением, все учатся. Из-за этого и ищу ответ от людей которые, возможно, подредактируют мой код. Не хочу оставлять весь этот код на "когда-то там".

Comment: Я имел в виду тот код который я прокомментировал, только эти пару строчек)

Comment: То что вы прокомментировали я понял.

Comment: Т.е. вот этот код у меня не вызывает сомнений почему добавляется именно знак минус, соответственно этот код нужно как-то дополнить чтобы было иное поведение. Но с поведением нужно разобраться, т.е. четко поставить себе задачу когда это будет знак а когда операция либо всегда только что-то одно. То что Вы привели весь код калькулятора конечно хорошо, но если бы был код лишь одной функции которая воспроизводит ту же проблему думаю намного легче было бы пофиксить код чтобы он работал как надо, ведь по сути визуальная часть тут особой роли не играет, можно было бы и в консоль что-то вывести;)

Comment: насколько я вижу нужно еще подправить функцию `calculate`чтобы она использовала операцию минус, это ведь там выполняются вычисления?

Comment: Да, там выполняются вычисления

Comment: мне кажется ответ которой предоставил @S. Nick наиболее подходящий, посмотрите все ли так работает, если да я бы выбрал этот ответ и разбирался бы почему эти  изменения сработали.

Comment: на мой взгляд в disign в `retranslateUi` просто перепутаны кнопки там где должно быть `btn_neg` нужно писать `btn_sub` и наоборот, тогда все работает + нужно поменять их расположения на лейауте

Comment: Изначальные предположения оказались ошибочны я отредактировал ответ

Comment: Извините, именно UI оказался важен для этого вопроса, несколько неожиданно, рад что с кодом по итогу оказалось все в порядке.